# Python proccess pool executor and named tuple leads to unit test error -> "cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object"

Tags: python, multiprocessing, namedtuple, process-pool

[image: snapshot of traceback]

I am trying to use namedtuple along with process pool executor and when writing a unit test , i keep getting an error below
The dut in the code represent the python file where i have the 2 functions stored and i am calling it from the unit test

Below is the code i have

```
def cr8_dfs_frm_parq(file,DEBUG=False):
    """Function to query each parquet and create 2 dataframes from the parquet.
        1) Dataframe (pivot table) with ECID as index, testname as columns and result as data
        2) Dataframe containing 2 columns, test time and testname 
        Both dataframes are required for Lean coverage analysis in function Parallel_execution

    Args:
        file (string): Path where the current parquet file is stored 

    Returns:
        pvt_df(df): Pivot table dataframe with testname as rows and ECID as cols and result as data
        data_df(df): dataframe containing list of tests and associated test time 
    """
    data_df = Query().get_data(user='temp', collection_or_file=file, parallel=False, max_cpu=1)
    if DEBUG:
        print("Name of the parquet file queried was - {} and it's shape is {}".format(os.path.basename(file),data_df.shape))
    
    if(set(data_df.columns.to_list()) != set(['ecid', 'tname_tnum', 'result', 'test_time'])):
        data_df = pd.DataFrame()
        pvt_df = pd.DataFrame()
        #providing an error to the user that the current file might be corrupt or not in format needed for script to process and will proceed to the next parquet
        log.error('Parquet file {} does not contain 4 columns as expected, please check and provide the correct parquet file with below columns \n {} .'.format(os.path.basename(file),list(['ecid', 'tname_tnum', 'result', 'test_time'])))
        
        return pvt_df,data_df

    data_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['tname_tnum','ecid'],keep = 'last',inplace=True) 
    data_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    #extracting pvt table of ecid,results and testname for lean coverage analysis
    pvt_df = data_df.pivot(index='ecid',columns='tname_tnum',values='result')
    #dataframe containing only test time and testname for creating a dictionary later
    data_df = data_df[['tname_tnum','test_time']]
    data_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['tname_tnum','test_time'],keep = 'last',inplace=True)


    if DEBUG :
        print("Pivot table shape after processing parquet {} is - {}".format(os.path.basename(file),pvt_df.shape))
    dfs_pr_parq = dfs(pvt_df,data_df)
    return dfs_pr_parq
```

```
def cr8_dfs_parl(max_cpu,parqs_lst,DEBUG=False):
    """Function that queries parquets parallel and creates 2 dataframes for lean coverage analysis later
        1) Dataframe with ECID as index, testname as column and results as data 
        2) Dataframe with test_time and testname as columns to create a test_time look up dictionary

    Args:
        max_cpu (int): Number of CPU cores to be used in parallel
        parqs_lst (list): List of parquets that need to be merged for computing Jaccard similarity 

    Returns:
        pvt_df(df): Dataframe containing ECID's, testname and results 
        ts_tt_df_cnct(df): Dataframe containing testname and testtime
    """

    pvt_df_cncat = pd.DataFrame()
    ts_tt_df_cncat = pd.DataFrame()
     
    if not (sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor >= 8):
        if DEBUG:
            print("Processing of parquets needs Python 3.8 or higher. Please upgrade your Python version from {}.{}.".format(sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor))
            print("Exiting Script : will not reduce parquets until Python version has been upgraded to 3.8 or higher as indicated above")
        
        raise RuntimeError(" Pythonn version {}.{} is old, please upgrade to Python 3.8 or higher for the python script to be run".format(sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor))

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_cpu) as executor:
        all_task = []
        for file in parqs_lst:
            all_task.append(executor.submit(cr8_dfs_frm_parq,file,DEBUG))
        
        for future in as_completed(all_task):
            dfs_pr_parq = future.result()
            #concatenate parquets and remove duplicate ECID's
            pvt_df_cncat = pd.concat([pvt_df_cncat,dfs_pr_parq.pvt_df],axis=0,copy=False)
            pvt_df_cncat = pvt_df_cncat.iloc[np.unique( pvt_df_cncat.index.values, return_index = True )[1]]
            #concatenating test time to calculate mean time across different parquets
            #come back and fix this
            ts_tt_df_cncat = pd.concat([ts_tt_df_cncat,dfs_pr_parq.ts_tt_df],copy=False)
            if DEBUG:
                print('Pivot table shape currently is - {}'.format(pvt_df_cncat.shape))
                print('Test time dataframe shape currently is - {}'.format(ts_tt_df_cncat.shape))
    #returning a named tuple with 2 dataframes for easier parsing between functions
    cnct_dfs = dfs(pvt_df_cncat,ts_tt_df_cncat)
    if DEBUG:
        print('Pivot table with ECID as index final shape is - {}'.format(cnct_dfs.pvt_df.shape))
        print('Test time dataframe final shape is - {}'.format(cnct_dfs.ts_tt_df.shape))
    return cnct_dfs
```

This leads to the error as you see below
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object

When i run the unit test with this, it causes the error you see

```
    def test04_cr8_dfs_parl(self):
        
        """ checks if execution of files happened in parallel and reported shape is as expected
        """
        
        #making a copy of old parquets to new directory to ensure that parquets are recent
        shutil.copytree(self.inp_dir,self.copy_dir,copy_function=shutil.copy)

        parqs_lst = dut.get_parquet_list(parquet_dir=self.copy_dir,no_of_weeks = 1)

        self.dfs =dut.cr8_dfs_parl(max_cpu=6,parqs_lst=parqs_lst,DEBUG=self.debug)

        # #verifying dataframe shape is correct
        # with self.subTest('shape1'):
        #     self.assertEqual(dut_dfs.pvt_df.shape, (5509, 2660))
        
        # with self.subTest('shape2'):
        #     self.assertEqual(dut_dfs.ts_tt_df.shape, (7570, 2))
        
        self.tearDownClass()
```

Below is the stack trace, missed it
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:

```
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 245, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr2/nandeepd/PTE_CHAR/effective_coverage_tool/jaccard_similarity/test/test_jaccard_similarity.py", line 135, in test04_cr8_dfs_parl
    self.dfs =dut.cr8_dfs_parl(max_cpu=6,parqs_lst=parqs_lst,DEBUG=self.debug)
  File "/usr2/nandeepd/PTE_CHAR/effective_coverage_tool/jaccard_similarity/jaccard_similarity.py", line 163, in cr8_dfs_parl
    dfs_pr_parq = future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 438, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 245, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.181s
```

Comment: You did not post a stack trace and since you did not post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I can't tell what data type a *parquet* is. It's not like everybody reading this question sees `dut` and recognizes what that module is and therefore what `dut,get_parquet_list` returns. But I suspect a *parquet* is an open file as returned by the Python `open` function and if so therein lies your problem. Open files cannot be serialized/deserialized from one address space to another.

Comment: @Booboo i have added the stack trace. Parquet is of type parquet (apache storage file) as in the parquet file you can use pandas, pd.read_parquet() on. Please check the stack trace now and let me know if you feel it is the same issue.  The dut represent the python file that contains the 2 functions which i am calling in the unit test. When i run the python program standalone i do not see the issue, but see an issue only when i run unit test

Comment: Did you post the *complete* stack trace for the first exception that caused the second exception? It should start with a line of code corresponding in your program.

Comment: yes, i have posted the complete trace andi have also added a snapshot of trace. Let me know